# How to dynamically change single TextView color on CustomAdapter?

Tags: java, android

I've a CustomAdapter and I'm trying to change its color according to the type of writing.

E.g.

If the string "categoria_label" will be equal to "apple" i want set a red background color on the textview if it is "pineapple" i want set yellow background and go on... this for each row of CustomAdapter

I've seen a loot of tutorial and i know that modify single line is possible in the getView() function of the CustomAdapter

In the Object PastChallenge there are a getter and a setter that retrieve me the color.

```
public String getColore_categoria() {
    return colore_categoria;
}

public String setColore_categoria(String colore_categoria) {
    this.colore_categoria = colore_categoria;
    return colore_categoria;
}
```

But i don't know how change it in CustomAdapter

Maybe i need to do a case?

CustomAdapter Code

```
public class PastChallengeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PastChallenge> {
    ArrayList<PastChallenge> PastChallengeList;
    LayoutInflater vi;
    int Resource;
    ViewHolder holder;

    public PastChallengeAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<PastChallenge> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Resource = resource;
        PastChallengeList = objects;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // convert view = design
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
            holder.Categoria = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Categoria);
            holder.FirstUserName= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.FirstUserName);
            holder.secondUserName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.secondUserName);
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }
        holder.Categoria.setText(PastChallengeList.get(position).getCategoria_label());
        holder.FirstUserName.setText(PastChallengeList.get(position).getUser_challenge_1());
        holder.secondUserName.setText(PastChallengeList.get(position).getUser_challenge_2());
        return v;

    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView Categoria;
        public TextView FirstUserName;
        public TextView secondUserName;
    }
```

Comment: where is ur backgroundcolor setting code?

Comment: It's what i'm trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

holder.Categoria.setBackgroundColor((Color.parseColor(PastChallengeList.get(position).getColore_categoria()));

Comment: And for set colour i need to identify textview by findviewbyid an then use setbackgroundcolor?

Comment: Check updated answer. you already have textview attached with holder. so use anyone or all

Comment: or if you want to set background for whole list item than define id to your Parent viewgroup that is LinearLayout or Relativelayout of your listview item and define it here in adapter and then set background color to that

Comment: I have dynamically label it is not static and this work for static label...

Comment: You need any static things . You can directly do from your adapter everything. Did you got the answer ? is it working now ?

Comment: There are n label and for each label there are an associated color

Comment: Ha so what you can do in your list only You can attach one more variable called colour_name and for each name you can set colour_name accordingly

Comment: Exactly and each label have different color for this i have the getColor_categoria() function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168717/discussion-between-trusted-and-abdevelopers).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `getView`

```
String label = PastChallengeList.get(position).getCategoria_label();

holder.Categoria.setText(label);

if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("apple"))
    holder.Categoria.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
else if(...)
    holder.Categoria.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
```

Comment: In which point of code beetween return v and holder.secondUserName?

Comment: after setting Categoria text

Comment: or somewhere before the return of your `getView`